# Expo version error: No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I've updated the expo version in my react native project from "~43.0.2" to "^48.0.4" and then the error from the title appears. The 43.0.2 version works perfectly, but the 48.0.4 version fails to work, showing me the next error:

WARN  No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

ERROR  Error: Expo native runtime is not available: something went wrong and we aren't sure what it was. Please post more information and get support at https://forums.expo.dev.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path
is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or
there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path
is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or
there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Has anyone seen in before?

I use the command yarn add expo to install it, but it only works if I install the "~43.0.2" version